# Unable to read repository XXXXXXXXXXX IDE Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

Every time when I try to get the `updates` of Eclipse, this window comes in & I already remove/uninstall it from `Uninstall` tab.

How can I remove/delete permanently this birt library.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable or remove updates site in the **preferences *Install/Update > Available Software Sites***.